# Weird :hover bug with z-index and img

Tags: html, css, image, hover, z-index

I am having a very weird bug trying to highlight some parts of an image with overlays (higher `z-index`) on `:hover`. In Safari / Firefox / Chrome, no issue. But in IE (8 or 9), my simple CSS code doesn't work as it seem that IE doesn't trigger the `:hover` when the overlays are not always visible (no `background-color` or `visibility:hidden`)

Here is a MWE with the HTML and CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .photo-notes {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 998;
    }
    .photo-notes ul {
      position: relative;
    }
   .photo-notes li {
      list-style: none;
      position: absolute;
      background: #ccc;
      z-index: 999;
    }
    .photo-notes li:hover {
      background: red;
    }
    .photo-container {
      z-index: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div class="photo-notes">
    <ul>
      <li style="left:  25px; top: 20px; width: 50px; height: 100px;"> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="photo-container">
    <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/newyearsday-2012-hp.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above works, but if you try to remove the `background: #ccc` or add `visibility:hidden` from/to the `li` styling, it stops working under IE (no more `:hover` effect).

The additional weird thing is that it does work (the `:hover` gets triggered) without `background` or with `visibility:hidden` on the `li` if the `<img>` line is removed. So it's not an issue of `:hover` not being possible on an element that's not visible in IE as one would think, and I've tried adding explicit `z-index`es everywhere without success...

Any idea of what's happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it myself by setting a background and `opacity:0` on the `li` (which for IE means `filter: alpha(opacity:0))`. This way, the `:hover` gets triggered properly.